# Routing error on 'new' path (uninitialized constant ErrorsController (ActionController::RoutingError))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm receiving an Action Controller exception on the 'new' path of http://bob.dev/assessments/new. I recently added Devise and Sextant to the project and the path that's giving me issue was working previously.

The exception:

`uninitialized constant ErrorsController (ActionController::RoutingError)`

The routes:

```
Bob::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  mount_sextant                                   # Sextant gem #####################
  match '*not_found' => 'errors#handle404'        # visit http://bob.dev/rails/routes
  match "*path" => 'errors#handle404'             ###################################

  # resources :users                              # Authentication from scratch #####
  # resources :sessions                           ###################################

  root :to => "assessments#index"
    resources :assessments
end
```

and finally, the output from http://bob.dev/rails/routes via Sextant:

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)           devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)          devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)             devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format) devise/confirmations#new
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#show
            rails_routes GET    /rails/routes(.:format)           rails/routes#index
             rails_route GET    /rails/routes/:id(.:format)       rails/routes#show
                                /*not_found(.:format)             errors#handle404
                                /*path(.:format)                  errors#handle404
                    root        /                                 assessments#index
             assessments GET    /assessments(.:format)            assessments#index
                         POST   /assessments(.:format)            assessments#create
          new_assessment GET    /assessments/new(.:format)        assessments#new
         edit_assessment GET    /assessments/:id/edit(.:format)   assessments#edit
              assessment GET    /assessments/:id(.:format)        assessments#show
                         PUT    /assessments/:id(.:format)        assessments#update
                         DELETE /assessments/:id(.:format)        assessments#destroy
                         GET    /rails/routes(.:format)           rails/routes#index
                         GET    /rails/routes/:id(.:format)       rails/routes#show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely remove the lines

```
  match '*not_found' => 'errors#handle404'        
  match "*path" => 'errors#handle404'
```

They're not needed. That will solve your error. Though if you want to make a custom error handler for your app check out number 3 in Jose's post http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/01/my-five-favorite-hidden-features-in-rails-3-2/

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the 'Errors' word is reserved and is conflicting in one of the new dependencies. Can you call those routes/controller something different?

Comment: That would be incorrect, you can check this yourself by making an errors_controller. After posting guesses, i usually try to figure out a way to validate them and include that in the post if it is too lengthy to try, helps the OP debug.

Comment: Good call, I should have added that as a comment, instead of an answer. I should have validated it before posting it, actually. I'll delete it in the morning.